# Drop-down displays before event

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, display

Longtime lurker, first time question asker. I have a weird event here...

I have a navigation bar at the top of my website with a few items having a drop-down. The drop-down will automatically display when the mouse is in the area where the drop-down would display. (See the image below). The red-arrow represents where my mouse is when the drop-down triggers.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHyFO.png)

I have feeling this is related to the z-index, but different combinations of z-index for the main content, and the sub-menu does not work. If I change the z-index to '-1' it will no longer display until you hover over 'Info', however it hides it behind the main content and makes the links unclickable.

*Edit* to include all CSS and HTML for menu. Thanks!

```css
#header {
  width: 970px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  border-top-width: thin;
  border-left-width: thin;
  border-right-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #444;
}

.clearfix: after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.menu-wrap {
  z-index: 1;
  margin: -13px 0px;
  float: right;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2e2728;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.menu>ul>li:hover>a,
.menu>ul>.current-item>a {
  background: #2e2728;
  height: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu li:after {
  content: '|';
  color: #2e2728;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sub-menu {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #2e2728;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #3e3436;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="socialmedia">
    other stuff
  </div>

  <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/urbanexplorations/">Urban Explorations</a></li>
        <li><a href="/galleries/">Galleries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography&#9662;</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/info/fineart.php">Fine&nbsp;Art&nbsp;Purchasing</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/weddings/">Weddings</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/realestate/">Real Estate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/videography">Videography</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Info&#9662;</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/info/statementandbio.php">Artist&nbsp;Statement&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/info/awardsandpublications.php">Awards&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Publications</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/info/events.php">Events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.jon-stone.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the dropdown appearing due to a Javascript condition or is it purely CSS?

Comment: Feels like we need some code for demonstration.

Comment: @Jon Stone: provide your full code so that it can be better understand and you can achieve your solution.

Comment: @KevinPastor and others...

Edited my post with the full code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the way the submenu is hidden. Since its `opacity` is set at `0`, the user can still hover the item as if it was there. You should instead look for a solution using `display: none`. With this, even if the user hovers the usually position of the hidden item, it will not be considered as hovered in the CSS condition.

Comment: Thanks! I set display: none for .sub-menu, and display: block for .menu li:hover .sub-menu {

I had my mind set on z-index and lost focus.